# Python. A user access token is required to request this resource

Tags: python, facebook

I am trying to send some facebook notification through Python facebook SDK.
Using the following HTTP request to do it:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<USER ID>/notifications?&access_token=<My APP access token>&template=My message!!!!
```

All requests return the following response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 102
   }
}
```

I have tried to do it manually in the browser. Result was the same. Facebook just says:

```
POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …
```

So any user access token is required....
How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your stil in development and just need a valid user token , go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and generate one from your own user account.

However, if you are already authenticating from python, the python facebook sdk provides a few options.

1. get_access_token_from_code
2. get_user_from_cookie
3. parse_signed_request

all of these provide access to the user access token that you can then use to sign our requests.